# iPhone reusable cell does not show the changed data while scrolling

Tags: iphone, uitableview, cell, reusability

I have a table view.  I have created a method that takes all the data it needs  with a cell and returns the updated cell. In that method I have:

my cell for row goes like this
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell = myCellcreationMethod : cell : reuseIdentifier: other arguments;
```

MycellCreation method goes like this:
MycellCreation with args some strings , the cell and the reuseIdentifier.

```
if ( cell == nil ) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    //Here code that creates a custom image view something like:
    thumbnailView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(9, 9, 70, 70)];
    thumbnailView = [imUtil getImageViewWithRoundedCorners:thumbnailView andRadius:10.0];
    thumbnailView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:thumbnailView];
    //same here for another image view,
    //same again
    //and there same for a UILabel
}
//Here I set in each case the data for each imageView from above and the UIlabel text like

UIImage *thumbnailImage = [imUtil getThumbnailImageWithFile:thumbnail];
thumbnailView.image = thumbnailImage;
//the others go here
textLabel.text = @"something";

return cell;
```

All cells have the same identifier since they all are of the same type. But when I scroll down, instead of showing the data that corresponds to the next object in my list (new thumbnail new image, new text in uilabel) it replicates the first ones. I guess it loads the reused cell but does not put the new data in.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Are u using storyboard? If yes did you set the content of your table view to Dynamic Prototypes and prototype cells to 1 in the attribute inspector of your table view. I guess those can be set programmatically too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I shouldn't just add the views with a method in my tableview class. I created a NEW subclass of UITableView, initialized it with my custom views and created a method in there that sets the new data. then used them two and it works like a charm!